# Want to use data from previous record into new one. (different position) Access

Tags: ms-access

So when I'm adding a new record i want it to use data from a different column. For example i have 2 columns, 1 with FromDestination and one with ToDestination. I want to use the ToDestination as FromDestination in the next Record. I have uploaded a Screenshot to give a clearer view of what i mean.

I have tried the Dlookup thing but since it's only usable for query's and form's it does not apply to me.

[image]

Comment: This is not going to happen without a form. Dlookup is not the answer, even with a form.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing what you want using a table.  Tables before Access 2010 cannot execute code at all, and even in Access 2010+, the macros are rather limited compared with VBA.  In particular, a Data Macro cannot set a value in another table in the Before Change event, and cannot change a value in the current record in an After... Event as it would cause a trigger loop.

On the other hand, you can make a form which starts in datasheet view by default (if that's what you want), which can do what you want quite easily (if you understand VBA reasonably well).